# how to solve the sampling rate conversion problem

Tags: sampling

I am trying to improve my DSP knowledge and this problem is too much for me. I am trying to solve following task: 
[image]
this is not a homework. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which book it is from? Take the frequency domain approach to solve this..

Comment: Equations are fairly straightforward. Your filter gain should be equal to $L$, cutoff frequency is always defined as $\omega/L$ and re-sampled frequency is $f_2=f_1\cdot L/M$.

Comment: @jojek: will you be post comment as the answer? i can accept it